# Is there a shorter Datetime construct for the following code?

Tags: php, date, datetime, unix-timestamp

Currently I am using such fragment:

```
if (is_numeric($date)) {
    $datetime = new DateTime('@'.$date);
} else {
    $datetime = new DateTime($date);
}
```

Where `$date` is either `unixtimestamp` or some date string like `2016/03/03`.

What are the best failsafe equivalent for this construct ?

Maybe some one-liner ? A wrapper class ?

I am asking about some shorter construct as we are using the above in many places in our system. So I would like to replace this with something more readable and failsafe.

Comment: Did you already try to use function date?

Comment: `$datetime = new DateTime((is_numeric($date) ? '@' : '') . $date);` ?

Comment: Does shorter really matter?

Comment: @JohnConde I have written an explanation about why.

Comment: Extend the **DateTime** class with a custom implementation and let it handle that kind of logic internally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something reusable across your project, wrap it in your own class, e.g.

```
class AcmeDateTime extends \DateTime
{
    public function __construct($time = "now", DateTimeZone $timezone = null)
    {
        $time = is_numeric($time) ? "@" . $time : $time;
        parent::__construct($time, $timezone);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) in php to shorten the `4` lines to a single line like this:

```
$datetime = new DateTime((is_numeric($date) ? '@' : '') . $date);
```